# CMake add_custom_command fails with bin/sh:1 : ... not found

Tags: cmake, intel, clion, intel-fpga

**What I want to achieve**

I try to set up a toolchain to compile OpenCL applications for Intel FPGAs. Therefore beneath building the C++ based host application I need to invoke the Intel OpenCL offline compiler for OpenCL kernels.

This step should only take place if the cl source file was edited or the resulting binaries are missing. My approach is to add a custom command to invoke the CL compiler and create a custom target that depends on the output generated by this command. The offline Open CL compiler is called `aoc` and due to the possibility of multiple SDK-Versions present on the system I invoke it with an absolute path that is stored in `aocExecutable`. This is the relevant part of my CMakeLists.txt

```
set (CLKernelName "vector_add")
set (CLKernelSourceFile "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${CLKernelName}.cl")
set (CLKernelBinary     "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${CLKernelName}.aocx")

add_executable (HostApplication main.cpp)

# ------ a lot of unneccessary details here ------ 

add_custom_command (OUTPUT  "${CLKernelBinary}"
                    COMMAND "${aocExecutable} -march=emulator ${CLKernelSourceFile} -o ${CLKernelBinary}"
                    DEPENDS "${CLKernelSourceFile}"
)


add_custom_target (CompileCLSources DEPENDS "${CLKernelBinary}")
add_dependencies (HostApplication CompileCLSources)
```

**What doesn't work**
Running this in the CLion IDE under Linux leads to this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /home/me/SDKsAndFrameworks/intelFPGA/18.1/hld/bin/aoc -march=emulator /home/me/CLionProjects/cltest/vector_add.cl -o /home/me/CLionProjects/cltest/cmake-build-debug-openclintelfpgasimulation/vector_add.aocx: not found
```

The whole command expands correctly, copying it and pasting it into a terminal works without problems, so I'm not sure what the `not found` error means.

**Further Question**

Assumed the above problem will be solved, how can I achieve that the custom command is not only invoked if the output file is not present in the build directory but also if the CL source file was edited?

Comment: As you can see in the error message, the bash interprets the **whole command line** as an *executable*. This is because you wrap `COMMAND` in your script with double quotes. Remove these double quotes, so everything will work. As for additional question, if you want `COMMAND` to be re-run on the file changed, then you need to add this file to `DEPENDS` list.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Your comment should be an answer, because it solves all my problems. Thank you for that. I'm quite new to CMake, I think I should have a read on when to use quotes and when not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in the error message, the bash interprets the **whole command line**

```
/home/me/SDKsAndFrameworks/intelFPGA/18.1/hld/bin/aoc -march=emulator /home/me/CLionProjects/cltest/vector_add.cl -o /home/me/CLionProjects/cltest/cmake-build-debug-openclintelfpgasimulation/vector_add.aocx
```

as a **single executable**.

This is because you wrap COMMAND in your script with **double quotes**.

Remove these double quotes, so everything will work.

---

As in many other scripting languages, in CMake double quotes makes the quoted string to be interpreted as a *single argument* for a function or for a macro.

But in `add_custom_command`/`add_custom_target` functions a keyword *COMMAND* starts a **list of arguments**, first of which denotes an executable and others - separated parameters for that executable.